# CKeditor plugin not working

Tags: plugins, ckeditor

I tried to setup the media Plugin from

http://forge.clermont-universite.fr/wiki/ckmedia and http://forge.clermont-universite.fr/projects/ckmedia/files

When including

```
CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'media';
```

in my page I get an error

`Error: uncaught exception: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "media" was not found at "http://localhost:8080/fileupload/ckeditor/plugins/media/plugin.js?t=B49E5BQ".`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a file not found error for that file.
Right click on the Tomcat server in Eclipse and choosing "Clean..." solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Please check, the directory name. It should be 'Media' or 'media' according to your media plugin file. On unix/linux systems... it matters. I was also facing problem on godaddy hosting but after looking at MediaEmbed plugin file, i find out that it was MediaEmbed not mediaembed.

Answer (score 0):

you should keep your plugin files(plugin.js, css, images) under `<plugin-name>` along with all plugins of ckeditor. See how core plugins are organised.

Answer (score 0):

We were getting this error because our node add/edit forms were being rendered within the website's theme, which may include a lot of unnecessary and/or incompatible javascript. For reliability, we switched to using the administration theme (in our case bartik), and then the javascript error disappeared. Hope this can help someone else out there.